# Wanted to update 10 random rows without ID and where condition

Tags: sql

I  wanted to update 10 random rows as `NULL` without `where` condition and without `using ID`.

```
SELECT [BusinessEntityID]
      ,[JobTitle]
      ,[BirthDate]
      ,[MaritalStatus]
  FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[Container_Destination]`
```

I am not able to do that. Please help me . Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, you presumably want to set *columns* to `NULL`, because setting a *row* to `NULL` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: SELECT   [BusinessEntityID]
      ,[JobTitle]
      ,[BirthDate]
      ,[MaritalStatus]
  FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[Container_Destination]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 ; with cte as (
  select top 10 * from [TestDB].[dbo].[Container_Destination])
  update cte set [BusinessEntityID] = null
  ,[JobTitle] = null
  ,[BirthDate] = null
  ,[MaritalStatus] = null
```

Comment: I do not use Where condition. My requirement is like that.